# verify user from rest api mysql

Tags: node.js

I want to verify user from rest api to db `mysql`. In my case, if giving username value false, the respond status not 404 but

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined.

**my router**

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res){
    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;
    User.findUser(username, function(err, user){
        if(err) return res.status(500).send('Error on the server');
        if(!user) return res.status(404).send('No user found');

        var passIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user[0].password);
        if(!passIsValid) return res.status(401).send({auth: false, token: null});

        var token = jwt.sign({id: username}, config.secret, {
            expiresIn: 86400

        });

        res.status(200).send({auth: true, token: token});
    });
});
```

**my model**

```
findUser: function(username, callback){
        let data = db.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=?",[username], callback, function(error, results, fields){
            if(error) throw err
            return results;
        });

    }
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Why you're not returning anything from the `findUser` method?

Comment: solved. i give condition object length == 0

Comment: To the body? Like the comments in my answer said, it should have given the error on username, not in password. There is something wrong in your question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Undefined body

I suppose that you're trying to get req.body.* from an undefined body. If you are not using bodyParser middleware or another similar your body is `undefined`. You can read it [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req).

Install bodyParser using `npm i --save body-parser` and add the middleware at the start of your middleware chain.

#### Callbacks

You're missing completely the point of using callbacks.

I understand that you are new either to javascript or to programming and I encourage you to learn about callbacks, promises, and the way javascript works, because your code is a mess.

I don't know what library are you using, but I bet that your findUser method should look more like this:

```
findUser: (username, callback) => {
  let data = db.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=?", [username], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) return callback(error, undefined)
    return callback(undefined, results)
  })
}
```

You are even trying to throw an undefined error named `err` inside findUser.

Comment: i use express js

Comment: I mean "db.query"

Comment: But if the body is `undefined` then why the error is not about `username`  (but `password)?

Comment: @sarneeh I had the same question, but seeing his code there are a lot of things that could be wrong really. I mean, he even try to throw an unexisting error. That bug could be anywhere.

Comment: @IvandelaBeldad Yeah, well, like you've said - there's something wrong with the question :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using Passport.JS for local authentication